# UNIX + nginx + php + SQL

Tags: linux, php, nginx

I use a FTP site to upload my work, which resides on a server running on a Linux OS based on nginx. And I use an odbc driver to connect to a database that interacts with my php code. In that database exists a date column type that returns the full date & time. I need to retrieve just the date. I used the `CONVERT` function `convert(varchar(10), date_col, 110)`and get the needed result using it withAptanaStudio as my IDE. But my php code returns an empty field. What have I done wrong?
The code:

```
<?php 
$odbc = odbc_connect(...);
$odbc_res = odbc_exec($odbc, "select convert(varchar(10), rep_date, 110) from table");                                                                            
?>
<table>
<thead>
<th>Date is:</th>                                             
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php $r = odbc_fetch_array($odbc_res_c) ?>
<tr>
<td><?= $r['rep_date'] ?></td>   
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There are lots of DBMS, which are you using?

Comment: AquaData Studio -> Sybase

Comment: Would you mind posting the php code that receives the date?

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 0):

So I used dancing with PHP code, and got the solution

`$r['rep_date'] = mb_substr(strval($r['rep_date']), 0, 10, 'UTF-8');`